# HandlebarsJS - nested #each not being output

Tags: handlebars.js

I am working on an app which outputs a table with data in it. I have the normal data being outputted correctly however I have a value which is returned as 'WWWWW' / 'WLDWD' (letters indicate Win/Draw/Loss). I have uploaded an image at the bottom which shows my table, including an each loop which is outside of the first #each loop which works as intended.

I have a table that is set out as following

Position    Club    Played  Won     Drawn   Lost    GF  GA  GD  Points  Form

I have an #each that loops through and outputs the values for those fields, I then have another #each within the first #each, I want this to output the recentForm, this is split on my index.js(shown below).

It returns the data as following 
`[ [ 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W' ],
  [ 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W' ],
  [ 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W' ],`

I use the code below to output it, if it is inside my other #each which outputs the other data, it doesn't run, however if it is outside the other #each it works perfectly.

```
{{#each recentForm}} 
   {{this.[0]}} // I have 5 of these (5 is the max that will ever be returned)
{{/each}}
```

Full Code:

```js
router.get('/table', (req, res, next) => {
  var url = `http://api.football-api.com/2.0/standings/1204${config.auth}`

  axios.get(url).then(response => {
    const posSort = response.data.sort((a, b) => {
      return a.position - b.position;
    });

    var recentForm = posSort.map(pos => pos.recent_form.split(''));
    console.log(recentForm);
    res.render('table', {
      teamStats: posSort,
      recentForm: recentForm
    });

  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })

});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Club</th>
    <th>Played</th>
    <th>Won</th>
    <th>Drawn</th>
    <th>Lost</th>
    <th>GF</th>
    <th>GA</th>
    <th>GD</th>
    <th>Points</th>
    <th>Form</th>
  </tr>
    {{#each teamStats}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{position}}</td>
        <td>{{team_name}}</td>
        <td>{{overall_gp}}</td>
        <td>{{overall_w}}</td>
        <td>{{overall_d}}</td>
        <td>{{overall_l}}</td>
        <td>{{overall_gs}}</td>
        <td>{{overall_ga}}</td>
        <td>{{gd}}</td>
        <td>{{points}}</td>
      // Below is the one I want to have working - it doesn't output anything when looping even the code is identical to the code outside this loop.
      {{#each recentForm}}
        <td>{{this.[0]}}</td>
      {{/each}}
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
      // Below works perfectly, loops through and outputs them in a td each
      {{#each recentForm}}
        <td>{{this.[0]}}{{this.[1]}}{{this.[2]}}{{this.[3]}}{{this.[4]}}</td>
      {{/each}}
</table>
```

[image: Table Output - with last the random letters on the bottom are the debugging #each loop which works as intended.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Fix

A combination of the [`../` operator](http://handlebarsjs.com/#paths) and [`lookup` helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup) should be used here. Note the nested helper syntax parentheses `()` rather than curly braces.

```js
{{#each (lookup ../recentForm @index)}}
  {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

The `../` operator helps grab the correct 'recentForm' property (top level, sibling of 'teamStats'), since the `#each` helper sets a new context. The `lookup` helper takes the `@index` of the 'teamStats' loop and passes the value of 'recentForm' at that index (i.e. the team the 'teamStats' loop is currently at).

Side-note, you'd probably only want a single `<td>` for the 'form' column to align with the single `<th>`, the snippet below is doing this.

Run/see snippet below.

```js
// shortened data for brevity
var data = {
  teamStats: [
    {team: 'Man U'},
    {team: 'Arsenal'}
  ],
  recentForm: [
    ['W','W','L','D','W'],
    ['L','L','L','D','W']
  ]
};


//inline template for snippet simplicity
var template = '' +
'<table>' +
'<thead>' +
'<tr>'+
'<th>Team Name</th>' +
'<th>Form</th>' +
'</tr>' +
'</thead>' +
'<tbody>' +
'{{#each teamStats}}' +
'<tr>' +
'<td>{{team}}</td>' +
// start 'form' cell
'<td>' +
'{{#each (lookup ../recentForm @index)}}' +
'{{this}}' +
'{{/each}}' +
'</td>' +
// end 'form' cell
'</tr>' +
'{{/each}}' +
'</tbody>' +
'</table>';

var output = Handlebars.compile(template)(data);
console.log(output)
// for snippet simplicity
$('body').html(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.12/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```

#### Alternative

Alternatively, it might be simpler to parse the 'recentForm' values and place them on a property within each 'teamStats' object. Then your template wouldn't need a more complex `../` and `lookup` and would just become:

```js
<td>{{recentForm}}</td>
```

```js
// shortened data for brevity
var teamStats = [
    {team: 'Man U'},
    {team: 'Arsenal'}
  ];
var recentForm = [
    ['W','W','L','D','W'],
    ['L','L','L','D','W']
  ];
// loop each team, and add recentForm at index
teamStats.forEach(function(team, index) {
  team.recentForm = recentForm[index].join(',');
});

var data = {
  teamStats: teamStats
};

var template = '' +
'<table>' +
'<thead>' +
'<tr>'+
'<th>Team Name</th>' +
'<th>Form</th>' +
'</tr>' +
'</thead>' +
'<tbody>' +
'{{#each teamStats}}' +
'<tr>' +
'<td>{{team}}</td>' +
'<td>{{recentForm}}</td>' +
'</tr>' +
'{{/each}}' +
'</tbody>' +
'</table>';

var output = Handlebars.compile(template)(data);
console.log(output)
// for snippet simplicity
$('body').html(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.12/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```